# Atom text editor on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, editors, atom-editor

I have a debian 8.7 installed raspberry pi 3 model B. I want to install github's atom text editor on my raspberry pi 3. How can I proceed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately `atom` is only available for the 64 bits systems .

[atom-github](https://github.com/atom/atom) :

> Debian Linux (Ubuntu)
>
> Atom is only available for 64-bit Linux systems

**Edit**

Alternative solution :

You can build Atom text editor on [OpenSuse](https://www.linux.com/news/learn/intro-to-linux/first-64-bit-and-enterprise-os-comes-raspberry-pi-3) following the steps described on [git repo](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/docs/build-instructions/linux.md)

> SLES (and openSUSE) are the only 64-bit operating systems for Raspberry Pi.

```
sudo zypper install nodejs nodejs-devel make gcc gcc-c++ glibc-devel git-core libgnome-keyring-devel rpmdevtools libX11-devel libxkbfile-devel
git clone https://github.com/atom/atom.git
cd atom
script/build
```

Comment: Newer ARM processors fully support 64bit. From wiki:  "The Raspberry Pi 3 uses a Broadcom BCM2837 SoC with a 1.2 GHz 64-bit quad-core ARM Cortex-A53 processor, with 512 KB shared L2 cache". 
ARM Cortex-A53 is an ARMv8-A, which introduced 64bit instruction sets (AArch64) Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A53

Comment: @Bruno9779 Only OpenSuse , Not Debian , see here https://www.linux.com/news/learn/intro-to-linux/first-64-bit-and-enterprise-os-comes-raspberry-pi-3

Comment: My bad, I thought that "raspbian switching to 64bit" thingie went through already. Please edit you answer so I can upvote

Comment: With '64-bit' system, they (somewhat inaccurately) mean x86_64 *only*. There's no way you'll be able to run that on you rpi3, unless you build the package yourself, or you use multiarch and qemu (but thzt will be extremely slow...). Additionally, while the RPi has a 64-bit CPU, the Raspbian distribution does not use the 64-bit features of that chip, instead sticking to 32-bit.